# Gradle version and gradle-wrapper.properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How do I download the latest Gradle version automatically within a Android project? Do I manually change the file gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
...
```

And change 2.4 to 2.6 and run gradlew?
When I create a Android project, why is not 2.6 there from start?

Comment: You have to change it manually.

Comment: When you sync the project, android studio will automatically download the new version of gradle.

Comment: Yes but only the 2.4 version not the 2.6 version? Why are they not downloading the latest stable?

Comment: I also noticed that the canary Android Studio use 2.4 and download it specifically, not using the wrapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I download the latest Gradle version automatically within a Android project? Do I manually change the file gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

**Yes.**
You have to change the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

For example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

Then, **sync** the project.
Android Studio will download the new version automatically.

> And change 2.4 to 2.6 and run gradlew?

First, sync the project.

> When I create a Android project, why is not 2.6 there from start?

The new project is based on a template file.
For this reason, currently any new project is with 2.4 version.

You can change the template, but AS will update it with the next updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it manualy, but I don't recommend it.Because the gradle wrapper version related to **gradlew** and **gradlew.bat**, they may need to change too.If your want to upgrade your gradle wrapper, run this in Android Studio Terminal if you using Linux:

`./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 2.10`

For Windows, change the command to

`gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 2.10`

Answer (score 0):

If you use macOs,
in android studio go

1. Android Studio
2. Preferences
3. Build, Execution, Deployment
4. Gradle, and change use gradle from: specified location
5. go to users/current_user
6. press commant+shift+dot (for show hidden files)
7. go to gradle folder
8. go to wrapper folder
9. open

Now gradle install all missing files, Good Luck :)